# Find all solutions of $4\cos^2(x)-4\sin(x)-5=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Find all solutions of $4\cos^2(x)-4\sin(x)-5=0$ in the interval $(6\pi, 8\pi)$.

I tried to work it out and got: $4y^2-4y -9 = 0$, but I can't figure out what $\cos x = $from there to finish the problem.

Comment: Does "y**2" mean $y^2$? [This post](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to format mathematics on this site.

Comment: I made the assumption MJD is asking about when I edited the question.  If the assumption is incorrect, please change back the edit. :)

Comment: yes it does mean that!

Comment: You are almost there. You made the substitution y=sin(x) and found the quadratic. Now solve for the roots of the quadratic. For any real root r : -1<=r<=1 you know r = sin(x). So calculate the inverse sin to get possible x and add appropriate numbers of 2*pi to get your solution in the right interval. No need to even know what cos(x) is...

Comment: ITT: Spoon-feeding

Answer (score 3):

$$\begin{align} 4\cos^2 x - 4\sin x - 5 & = 0 \\ \\\iff 4(1 - \sin^2 x) & = 4\sin x + 5 \\ \\  \iff 4\sin^2 x + 4\sin x + 1 &= 0\end{align}$$

---

$$\begin{align} y = \sin x \implies 4y^2 + 4y + 1 & = 0 \\ \\
(2y+1)^2 & = 0 \\ \\
\implies y & = -1/2\end{align}$$

---

Therefore $y = \sin x = -1/2 \implies x = \sin^{-1}(-1/2) = 7\pi/6, 11\pi/6$. That's in the interval $x \in (0, 2\pi).$

Adding $6\pi$ to each for the appropriate solutions in your given interval, we have solutions $$x \in \left\{\dfrac{43\pi}{6}, \dfrac{47\pi}{6}\right\}$$

Comment: How are you my dear friend? No news......:(+

Comment: @amWhy: Needs another Tu! +1

Answer (score 0):

If $\sin(x) = y$, $\cos(x) = \pm \sqrt{1-y^2}$.  But your equation for $y$ is not quite right.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\begin{align}
4\cos^2x -4\sin x -5 & = 0 \\
\Rightarrow 4(1-\sin^2x)-4\sin x -5 &=0 \\
\Rightarrow 4\sin^2x+4\sin x +1 &=0 
\end{align}
$$

Let $\sin x =t$

$$\Rightarrow 4t^2+4t+1=0$$

Solving this equation you get

$$\begin{align}
t & =\frac{-1}{2} \\ 
\Rightarrow \sin x & = \frac{-1}{2}  \\ 
\Rightarrow \sin x & = 240^\circ ; 330^\circ
\end{align}
$$

[ As $\sin x$ is negative therefore it lies in third or fourth quadrant]

Comment: Are you leaving the conversion (back?) to radians - and finding solutions in the given interval - as an exercise?

Answer (score 0):

As already found, $\sin x=\frac12$ which is $=\sin(-\frac\pi6)$

$$\implies x=n\pi+(-1)^n\left(-\frac\pi6\right)$$

If $n$ is even, $=2m$(say),

$x=2m\pi-\frac\pi6=(12m-1)\frac\pi6 $ and we need $6\pi<x<8\pi\implies 6\pi<(12m-1)\frac\pi6<8\pi  \implies\frac{37}{12}<m<\frac{49}{12}\implies m=4$
$\implies x=(12\cdot4-1)\frac\pi6=\frac{47\pi}6 $

Similarly, if $n$ is odd $=2m+1$(say)